# package terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'

Tags: ros, px4, ros-melodic, roslaunch, jetson

[image: Rosanswers logo]

this question might be better suited for px4 forums, but no one replies there.

When I try to launch a particular node/module on jetson TX2, it terminates and shows this error

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
[local_planner_node-2] process has died [pid 20132, exit code -6, cmd /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/lib/local_planner/local_planner_node __name:=local_planner_node __log:=/home/user/.ros/log/80e889fe-d9b5-11eb-8fd5-48b02d0f174f/local_planner_node-2.log].
log file: /home/user/.ros/log/80e889fe-d9b5-11eb-8fd5-48b02d0f174f/local_planner_node-2*.log
```

the same package with the same launch file works on my intel laptop, both have the same ros melodic installed, and both have ubuntu 18.04 installed. (laptop 18.04.5, Jetson 18.04.3).

Log files, and terminal outputs can be seen [here](https://github.com/PX4/PX4-Avoidance/issues/651).

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/381541/package-terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-%27std::logic_error%27/) by [rosnroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/76716/rosnroll/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2021-07-01

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It was a wrong version of Cmake. During rebuilding of package i found that, i get this error

```
CMake Warning (dev) at /home/user/cmake-install/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:273 (message):   The package name passed to `find_package_handle_standard_args` (PCL_APPS)   does not match the name of the calling package (PCL).  This can lead to   problems in calling code that expects `find_package` result variables   (e.g., `_FOUND`) to follow a certain pattern. Call Stack (most recent call first):   /usr/lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/cmake/pcl/PCLConfig.cmake:911 (find_package_handle_standard_args)   CMakeLists.txt:24 (find_package) This warning is for project developers.  Use -Wno-dev to suppress it.
```

launch file had a lot of find module lines in it, which caused it to pass a null to string values. causing this error.

---

Originally posted by [rosnroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/76716/rosnroll/) with karma: 18 on 2021-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-07-03**:\

> launch file had a lot of find module lines in it,

this sentence confuses me quite a bit, as `$(find ..)` in a `.launch` file does not use CMake.

Neither does CMake use `roslaunch`.

**Comment by [rosnroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/76716/rosnroll/) on 2021-07-04**:
I am very new to all this, i am trying to make sense of it all.
I replaced the *find package* lines with absolute values in .launch files, so the std::logic disappeared during launch.
But they reappear, when i change the ROS_MASTER_URI, or when i have this node be a part of complete system.
I rebuild the workspace using default version of CMake, then the find package warnings during build disappeared, but the overall behavior is still same.